# How to run chef cookbooks in terraform script?

Tags: chef-infra, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am provisioning aws infrastructure with the help of terraform script.

For example, I am creating four unix ec2 instance, Now I want to install tomcat in all 4 instance throw chef cookbook.

I want to run chef cookbook in terraform script and I tried with below code but it gives me errors.

```
resource "aws_instance" "LG" { ami = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX" instance_type = "XXXXXXXX" chef_role_name = ["../tomcat.json"]

Error: Unsupported argument

  on LG.tf line 16, in resource "aws_instance" "LG":
      chef_role_name  = ["../tomcat.json"]
```

Is this is correct way to call cookbook? can some one plz suggest.

Comment: Why do you think that would work? Have you read the docs on provisioners?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a provisioner to the resource. Something like this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "LG" {
    provisioner chef {
          chef_role_name  = ["tomcat"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this page. interesting one.

https://miirojuuso.com/blog/terraform-chef-quick-start

please feel free to check for your scope.

Comment: do not post link-only answer please